# XSLT issue compare two xpath and transform xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to create a xslt by comparing two different xpath and get value from both the children s and transform XML.

Rule as below:

```
1.)I need to compare the location-number inside buildings/building/building-header/location-number with buildings/policy/coverages/coverage/location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object/insured-object-nr and for the locations not matching i need to create element Policy/PolicyConditions/Name as No coverage and map the Policy/PolicyConditions/PolicyConditionCriteria/Value as the building-number ie.,LU4-B1 in my below example.

2.)for each buildings/policy/coverages/coverage check for limit/limit-type/@code is Bla and for each location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object/insured-object-nr check for location-number inside buildings/building/building-header/location-number and get the
buildings/building/building-header/building-number create Policy/PolicyConditions/Name as EQ Blanket and map the Policy/PolicyConditions/PolicyConditionCriteria/Value as the building-number LU1-B1,LU1-B1,LU2-B2

3.)for each buildings/policy/coverages/coverage check for limit/limit-type/@code is Sub and for each location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object/insured-object-nr check for location-number inside buildings/building/building-header/location-number and get the
buildings/building/building-header/building-number create Policy/PolicyConditions/Name as EQ Sublimit and map the Policy/PolicyConditions/PolicyConditionCriteria/Value as the building-number LU2-B1,LU2-B2,LU3-B1,LU3-B2

Rule 2 and 3 are more or less the same only check that is different is with the limit/limit-type/@code.
```

iam able to acheive rule 2 and rule 3 but not able to write logic to acheive rule 1 for the xpaths that are not matched.

I can use only xslt version 1.0

Input:

```
<buildings>
<building>
            <building-header>
                <location-number>LU1</location-number>
                <building-number>LU1-B1</building-number>
            </building-header>
</building> 
<building>
            <building-header>
                <location-number>LU2</location-number>
                <building-number>LU2-B1</building-number>
            </building-header>
</building>
<building>
            <building-header>
                <location-number>LU2</location-number>
                <building-number>LU2-B2</building-number>
            </building-header>
</building>
<building>
            <building-header>
                <location-number>LU3</location-number>
                <building-number>LU3-B1</building-number>
            </building-header>
</building>
<building>
            <building-header>
                <location-number>LU3</location-number>
                <building-number>LU3-B2</building-number>
            </building-header>
</building>
<building>
            <building-header>
                <location-number>LU4</location-number>
                <building-number>LU4-B1</building-number>
            </building-header>
</building>     

<policy-details>
<coverages>
<coverage>
<limit>
        <limit-type code="Bla"/>
</limit>
<location-rule>
                        <insured-objects>
                            <insured-object>
                                <insured-object-nr>LU1</insured-object-nr>
                            </insured-object>
                            <insured-object>
                                <insured-object-nr>LU2</insured-object-nr>
                            </insured-object>
                        </insured-objects>
</location-rule>
</coverage>
<coverage>
<limit>
        <limit-type code="Sub"/>
</limit>
<location-rule>
                        <insured-objects>
                            <insured-object>
                                <insured-object-nr>LU2</insured-object-nr>
                            </insured-object>
                            <insured-object>
                                <insured-object-nr>LU3</insured-object-nr>
                            </insured-object>
                        </insured-objects>
</location-rule>
</coverage>
</coverages>
</policy>
</buildings>
```

SAMPLE XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<policy>
<xsl:for-each select="//coverage">
<xsl:if test="limit/limit-type/@code='Bla'">
<PolicyConditions>
<Name>EQ Blanket</Name>
<xsl:for-each select="location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object">
<xsl:variable name="var_Ins_Obj">
    <xsl:value-of select="insured-object-nr"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="//building">
                                                    <xsl:variable name="var_loc_Num">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="building-header/location-number"/>
                                                    </xsl:variable>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$var_loc_Num=$var_Ins_Obj">
                                                        <xsl:variable name="locBuild">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="building-header/building-number"/>
                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                        <PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                                            <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
                                                            <Value>
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="$locBuild"/>
                                                            </Value>
                                                        </PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</PolicyConditions>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="limit/limit-type/@code='Sub'">
<PolicyConditions>
<Name>EQ Sublimit</Name>
<xsl:for-each select="location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object">
<xsl:variable name="var_Ins_Obj">
    <xsl:value-of select="insured-object-nr"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="//building">
                                                    <xsl:variable name="var_loc_Num">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="building-header/location-number"/>
                                                    </xsl:variable>
                                                    <xsl:if test="$var_loc_Num=$var_Ins_Obj">
                                                        <xsl:variable name="locBuild">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="building-header/building-number"/>
                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                        <PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                                            <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
                                                            <Value>
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="$locBuild"/>
                                                            </Value>
                                                        </PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</PolicyConditions>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</policy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual output:

```
<policy>
   <PolicyConditions>
      <Name>EQ Blanket</Name>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU1-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU2-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU2-B2</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
   </PolicyConditions>
   <PolicyConditions>
      <Name>EQ Sublimit</Name>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU2-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU2-B2</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU3-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU3-B2</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
   </PolicyConditions>
```

Expected output:

```
<Policy>
   <PolicyConditions>
      <Name>No Coverage</Name>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU4-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
   </PolicyConditions>
   <PolicyConditions>
      <Name>EQ Blanket</Name>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU1-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU2-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU2-B2</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
   </PolicyConditions>
   <PolicyConditions>
      <Name>EQ Sublimit</Name>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU2-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU2-B2</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU3-B1</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
      <PolicyConditionCriteria>
         <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
         <Value>LU3-B2</Value>
      </PolicyConditionCriteria>
   </PolicyConditions>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="noCoverage">
        <xsl:for-each select="//building/building-header/location-number">
            <xsl:variable name="locationNumber" select="text()"/>
            <xsl:if test="boolean(//coverage/location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object/insured-object-nr[text()=$locationNumber]) = false">
                <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <policy>
            <xsl:if test="contains($noCoverage, 'true')">
                <PolicyConditions>
                    <Name>No Coverage</Name>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//building/building-header/location-number">
                        <xsl:variable name="locationNr" select="text()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="boolean(//coverage/location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object/insured-object-nr[text()=$locationNr]) = false">
                            <PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
                                <Value>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../building-number"/>
                                </Value>
                            </PolicyConditionCriteria>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>     
                </PolicyConditions>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:for-each select="//coverage">
                <xsl:if test="limit/limit-type/@code='Bla'">
                    <PolicyConditions>
                        <Name>EQ Blanket</Name>
                        <xsl:for-each select="location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object">
                            <xsl:variable name="var_Ins_Obj">
                                <xsl:value-of select="insured-object-nr"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//building">
                                <xsl:variable name="var_loc_Num">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="building-header/location-number"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:if test="$var_loc_Num=$var_Ins_Obj">
                                    <xsl:variable name="locBuild">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="building-header/building-number"/>
                                    </xsl:variable>
                                    <PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                        <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
                                        <Value>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$locBuild"/>
                                        </Value>
                                    </PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </PolicyConditions>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="limit/limit-type/@code='Sub'">
                    <PolicyConditions>
                        <Name>EQ Sublimit</Name>
                        <xsl:for-each select="location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object">
                            <xsl:variable name="var_Ins_Obj">
                                <xsl:value-of select="insured-object-nr"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//building">
                                <xsl:variable name="var_loc_Num">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="building-header/location-number"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:if test="$var_loc_Num=$var_Ins_Obj">
                                    <xsl:variable name="locBuild">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="building-header/building-number"/>
                                    </xsl:variable>
                                    <PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                        <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
                                        <Value>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$locBuild"/>
                                        </Value>
                                    </PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </PolicyConditions>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </policy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, I added a variable where I check if there is a location-number with no corresponding insured-object-nr. If there is, I add to the value of the variable the string 'true'.

Then, inside the template I check the variable name, and, again, check whether the current location-number does not have a corresponding insured-object-nr.

Comment: Thanks for the solution it helped a lot.

Comment: Dear Maria,We found that there is a limitation in this approach,The approach  assumes the elements insured-object-nr and and location-number are located in one unique XPATH. If the xml changes and there are new elements with same name  in the future with different xpath, we would not notice that and run into errors.Is there any alternative for that?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the xpath, like you did in the other parts of the xslt. I will edit my answer.